# How I can I tell which ng-repeat item that the directive callback was made from?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a dropdown directive that can be called with a callback parameter. This callback is then called from the directive when the user selects an option in the dropdown. A working callback function looks like this:

```
myDirectiveCallback(selectedItem){
    //Do something with the selectedItem
}
```

I want to use this directive in an ng-repeat and I want to be able to know in which one of the dropdowns (which item in the ng-repeat) that the selection was made and the callback was called from.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myListOfItems">
    <my-directive callback="myDirectiveCallback"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Is there any way of doing this without updating the directive?

Comment: wouldn't it just be `<my-directive callback="myDirectiveCallback(item)"></my-directive>`?

Comment: can you just add something thats on the `$scope` like before `my-directive` but after `ng-repeat` can you add a `{{item.id}}` or whatever you have associated with the scope?

Comment: @Claies No. In the directive the callback is called like "scope.callback(selection);" I want access to both the selected value and the ng-repeat item in the callback function but when I write "myDirectiveCallback(item)" I don't know which ng-repeat item the callback was made from.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? is the `item` not the `selection`?

Comment: No, maybe I wasn't clear enough. `selection` is the value that is selected in the dropdown. `item` is the item in myListOfItems.

Answer (score 1):

Add another attribute to your directive so that you can pass it `item` and then reference it within the scope of the directive so that you can pass it to your callback (or whatever else you need it for).

You didn't include your directive code, so I'm just going to try to show you what I mean:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      currentItem: '=currentItem'  // could just use '=' since names match
    },
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html'
  };
});
```

Then add the currentItem attribute with the current item to the directive call:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myListOfItems">
    <my-directive currentItem="item" callback="myDirectiveCallback"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work but I was curious to if there is some way to solve this problem without updating the directive.

Comment: My gut tells me the answer to that is "no".  The directive has it's own isolated scope, so if you want to allow it to access items in its parent's scope, you have to explicitly bind to them in the directive definition.